# Proportional Relationship Between Velocity and Radius of a Balloon? Radius of a Parachute?

Tags: space

So I need to know the proportional relationship between velocity and radius of a parachute. I am building a near-space balloon in physics class and have to do some claculations. How do I do so using the drag force equation?

Also, what equation and how do I use for finding proportionality between a balloon's radius and velocity?

Knowing **how** to find it would be more appreciated than just **knowing** it.

Thank you!